# send SNS notification when health of the service goes down in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

When there is issue with aws we could go and see in aws personalized dashboard which service is being affect. I would like to receive notification when such event occurs. Is there a way to notifications for these? The once specific I am looking for are the "Operational" issues. How do I get alert for these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do this though CloudWaetch Events. More details are here:

- [Monitoring AWS Health events with Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html)

> You can use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to detect and react to changes in the status of AWS Personal Health Dashboard (AWS Health) events. Then, based on the rules that you create, CloudWatch Events invokes one or more target actions when an event matches the values that you specify in a rule. Depending on the type of event, **you can send notifications**, capture event information, take corrective action, initiate events, or take other actions.

Comment: My requirement is related to " These events aren't specific to AWS accounts, so they aren't published to CloudWatch Events. These event types have the word "operational" in the title in the Personal Health Dashboard, such as "SWF operational issue"." How would i get alerts for these.

Comment: @kumar If you got to CW rules and look for SWF for example, there is an event called "AWS_SWF_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE". Is this different operational issue then the one you are after?